# Multiple Applications and DynamoDB, Ideal way to configure?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We are planning to use DynamoDB as noSQL database for different applications running in AWS, and are planning to use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) for connection to DynamoDB.

Normally you have one AWS account, and you can create new users per application and you can give them access to their respective tables in DynamoDB, to ensure they cannot access/modify other applications data.

My question is, can application use the same name table in DynamoDB? e.g. LOG, so each application has it's own LOG table in DynamoDB, but the data is not shared? (we can achieve this in SQL based databases by defining the schema for each application and creating user who have required access to it's schema)

Note: We are not planning to use different DynamoDB regions and like to know if it is possible using one region?

Answer (score 21):

DynamoDB doesn't provide namespacing-levels such as `Database` and `Schema` like common SQL RDBMS, e.g. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CREATE), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT111).

> `[hostname > ] database > schema > table`

With DynamoDB its more like this

> `[aws-region > aws-account-id > ] table`

So you have two choices of separating applications accessing DynamoDB:

1) Simply use table name prefixes to separate tables being
application specific an use IAM to make sure 'App A' has only access
to the tables it requires access to.

- Pro:

  - easy to use, only separate what needs to be separated
  - ability to share DynamoDB tables between apps if needed
- Con:

  - billing, reporting

**or**

2) Use separate AWS Accounts.

- Pro:

  - separate billing, usage statistics etc.
- Con:

  - can be annoying to administrate, e.g. login/logout of AWS Console

**Note:** In general, you should not hard-code DynamoDB table names in your application. Use some mapping of logical-table names to real-table names. e.g. some variable `tableName_LOG = 'AppA_LOG'`.

Comment: I came across [this aws info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html) (see example 5) which cautions about using test and production instances under the same aws account as usage in one can affect the other. Makes sense but short of creating separate accounts doesn't offer any other suggestions. Would be great if AWS had some namespaces or something for this.

Comment: Also, [Cross account acccess](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-access-in-the-aws-management-console/) and [Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/) (the later coming in 2017 hopefully) can probably help with the billing and organisation sides of things.

Comment: Assuming that you put everything on 1 account, you may be able to split out cost and usage statistics by assigning tags on your resources in advance. 
Well, at least that's what I'm going to try now. :-)